# What is the range of OpenGL texture ID?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, graphics, textures

I have an object which owns a property Texture_ID. I need to initialize the value for Texture_ID in constructor, so I want some value unused by OpenGL to present that the texture is not yet set.

I don't know whether zero (0) is a good value? If there is a range that OpenGL applies to texture IDs, I want a value out of this range. Any idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

0 is the value you're looking for (to represent an unset texture ID/uncreated texture), as 0 is never a valid texture ID.

Comment: +1 See [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindTexture.xml) "The value zero is reserved to represent the default texture for each texture target."

Comment: @chris: does user786653 say the truth? if so, possibly i must use the max value of GLuint?

Comment: @Paul: Any texture object you create will have a non-zero value. If that's how you intend to use this class, zero is perfectly fine.

Comment: the opengl reference about glGenTextures doesn't state what value will be returned. maybe i just riskily use this zero '0'. tks chris and martin

Comment: @Paul He seems to be right. But regarding the OpenGL reference "default texture" is just another term for "no texture" or "no application created texture object". So passing 0 to `glBindTexture` doesn't cause an error, but it also doesn't have any effect (or an undefined effect, black texture, or something). So 0 is perfectly suited for representing an unitialized/invalid texture.

Comment: Actually the whole "default texture" thing is an anachronism of OpenGL-1.0 where there were yet no texture objects. To have multiple textures one would either use glTexImage before drawing the to be textured geometry, or use display lists to encapsulate the texture images therein; this is also the reason why sharing display lists will share textures in modern OpenGL. Since there were no texture objects, but only a texturing unit, OpenGL-1.1 introduced the term "default texture" as a failsafe for legacy (back then already) OpenGL-1.1 programs.

Comment: I meant "…legacy OpenGL-1.0 programs." of course. To late to edit that comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather initialize the texture in the constructor. That way you never have an object in an invalid state.

Comment: but in my project, the object is initialized when it doesn't yet have a texture. just a limitation of the project. for example: i have to show a cube with colors, then open an image file to get textures to draw on the cube, so in this case, when in the constructor, the texture is not known yet

Comment: Constructors may be called before there is a valid OpenGL context, which would cause several problems.

Comment: @datenwolf: if I have an object that represents an OpenGL texture object, that object is meaningless without an OpenGL context.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: In that case a good OOP design would make sure that by convention a OpenGL context (or context encapsulating reference) must be passed to the texture object constructor. Good library design can be recognized by that it is hard to use the library in a wrong way.

Comment: @datenwolf: yes, I absolutely agree.

Answer (score 3):

`0` is the value OpenGL uses for its own default texture. It never returns that value to you and you can use that value for your error checking.

I would although suggest using `-1`.

Comment: texture ID is GLuint, which means 'unsigned int', i don't think '-1' is valid

Comment: Then use `0xffffffff`. It's still `-1` to YOU!