# Using unique_ptr to control a file descriptor

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, gcc4.7

In theory, I should be able to use a custom pointer type and deleter in order to have `unique_ptr` manage an object that is not a pointer. I tried the following code:

```
#ifndef UNIQUE_FD_H
#define UNIQUE_FD_H

#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>

struct unique_fd_deleter {
    typedef int pointer; // Internal type is a pointer

    void operator()( int fd )
    {
        close(fd);
    }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<int, unique_fd_deleter> unique_fd;

#endif // UNIQUE_FD_H
```

This doesn't work (gcc 4.7 with the `-std=c++11` parameter). It responds with the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/memory:86:0,
                 from test.cc:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = int; _Dp = unique_fd_deleter]':
test.cc:22:55:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/unique_ptr.h:172:2: error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'std::nullptr_t' to binary 'operator!='
```

From delving into the definition of `unique_ptr`, I can see two problems that prevent it from working. The first, which seems in clear violation of the standard, is that the destructor for `unique_ptr` compares the "pointer" (which is, as per my definition, an int) to `nullptr` in order to see whether it is initialized or not. This is in contrast to the way it reports it through the boolean conversion, which is to compare it to `"pointer()"` (an uninitialized "pointer"). This is the cause of the errors I am seeing - an integer is not comparable to a `nullptr`.

The second problem is that I need some way to tell `unique_ptr` what an uninitialized value is. I want the following snippet to work:

```
unique_fd fd( open(something...) );

if( !fd )
    throw errno_exception("Open failed");
```

For that to work, `unique_ptr` needs to know that an "uninitialized value" is -1, as zero is a valid file descriptor.

Is this a bug in `gcc`, or am I trying to do something here that simply cannot be done?

Comment: I will add the obvious. Instead of "int", I can set the pointer type to some class I invent. This will allow me to do everything I want to. This will not, however, be a trivial class, as it requires back and forth implicit casts to int and other things I would rather avoid.

Comment: I suggest you stop using `std::unique_ptr` for non-pointer storage. It expects the data to actually _be_ a pointer, while you want it to be a _non-pointer_.

Comment: Wrap the file API's inside another class (RAII) that opens the file and stores the file descriptor. The class should close the descriptor when destructor is called. Then use use unique pointer of such class.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Then, there should be a class `std::handle` similar to `std::unique_ptr` but without `operator*`, and two extra template parameters: `class handle_type=void*`, and `handle_type null_value=nullptr`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The type exposed by the `Deleter::pointer` must satisfy [the `NullablePointer` requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/NullablePointer). Chief among them, this expression must be legal: `Deleter::pointer p = nullptr;`. Of course, `nullptr` is pretty much defined by the fact that it *cannot* be implicitly converted to a number, thus this doesn't work.

You'll have to use a type which can be implicitly constructed with `std::nullptr_t`. Something like this:

```
struct file_desc
{
  file_desc(int fd) : _desc(fd) {}
  file_desc(std::nullptr_t) : _desc(-1) {}

  operator int() {return _desc;}

  bool operator ==(const file_desc &other) const {return _desc == other._desc;}
  bool operator !=(const file_desc &other) const {return _desc != other._desc;}
  bool operator ==(std::nullptr_t) const {return _desc == -1;}
  bool operator !=(std::nullptr_t) const {return _desc != -1;}

  int _desc;
};
```

You can use that as the `Deleter::pointer` type.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference to the NullablePointer requirement for unique_ptr?

Comment: You should use `-1` for `nullptr`. `0` is a valid fd (although rarely closed).

Answer (score 13):

Can you do something simple like the following?

```
class unique_fd {
public:
    unique_fd(int fd) : fd_(fd) {}
    unique_fd(unique_fd&& uf) { fd_ = uf.fd_; uf.fd_ = -1; }
    ~unique_fd() { if (fd_ != -1) close(fd_); }

    explicit operator bool() const { return fd_ != -1; }

private:
    int fd_;

    unique_fd(const unique_fd&) = delete;
    unique_fd& operator=(const unique_fd&) = delete;
};
```

I do not see why you had to use `unique_ptr`, which is designed to manage pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).
Look in the examples code:

```
    void close_file(std::FILE* fp) { std::fclose(fp); }
    ...
    {
      std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, decltype(&close_file)> fp(std::fopen("demo.txt",                                                             
                                                                      "r"), 
                                                           &close_file);
      if(fp)     // fopen could have failed; in which case fp holds a null pointer
         std::cout << (char)std::fgetc(fp.get()) << '\n';
    }// fclose() called here, but only if FILE* is not a null pointer
     // (that is, if fopen succeeded)
```

Tried it in vs2019 and it works!
Also tried it with member and lambda:

FileTest.h:

```
class A
{
  std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, std::function<void(std::FILE*)>> fp;
}
```

FileTest.cpp

```
void A::OpenFile(const char* fname)
{
    fp = std::unique_ptr < std::FILE, std::function<void(std::FILE*)>>(
        std::fopen(fname, "wb"),
        [](std::FILE * fp) { std::fclose(fp); });
}
```

Comment: File descriptors are a POSIX / BSD concept - `FILE *` is a portable C (stdio) library API abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

A complete sample:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER 
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include <memory>
#include <fcntl.h>

template<auto nullvalue, auto delete_>
class unique
{
    using T = decltype(nullvalue);

    struct generic_delete
    {
        class pointer
        {
            T t;
        public:
            pointer(T t) : t(t) {}
            pointer(std::nullptr_t = nullptr) : t(nullvalue) { }
            explicit operator bool() const { return t != nullvalue; }
            operator T() const { return t; }
        };

        void operator()(T p)
        {
            delete_(p);
        }
    };
public:
    using type = std::unique_ptr<struct not_used, generic_delete>;
};

int main()
{

    using unique_fd = unique<-1, close>::type;
    static_assert(sizeof(unique_fd) == sizeof(int), "bloated unique_fd");
    unique_fd fd1(open("fd.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC));
    if (fd1.get() != -1)
        write(fd1.get(), "hello\n", 6);
}
```

Comment: Why/how is this working? I though `std::unique_ptr<>()` would transform it's first template parameter in a pointer (so `T * t` and not just `T t`) and so internally it would store `int *` which would require an extra allocation...

Comment: The deleter::pointer type, if it exists, overrides the template parameter and is stored internally by unique_ptr. The result type of deleter::pointer::operator* still must match the template parameter.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and it failed badly when I used the `*` operator because it's actually incorrect to apply such and your example is bogus. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86296 -- That operator can be replaced with `operator T () const` which returns `t` as is. To get the value you do `ptr.get()`. The `*ptr` syntax will fail compiling, which is normal. As mentioned in the bug report above, that's because you're returning a reference to a temporary. The deleter needs to be fixed too, of course, since it uses `*p` instead of `static_cast<T>(p)`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke ouch. I think supporting operator* was a mistake. Not only you accessed dangling references; you could do *fd = 42; at any time and leak. See revised version.

Comment: Yes. Actually there is a copy of the pointer class so the assignment was not so good but it would not really leak anything. At least the C++ library implementation that I use makes a copy of the pointer class so you were only changing the copy (although, since it was a temporary copy...) and the pointer class does not call the deleter. I have more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015016/#51033600

Answer (score 2):

The open source Android Framework defines a unique_fd class that might meet your needs: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/c0e6e40/base/include/android-base/unique_fd.h

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't coerce a (smart) pointer to be a non-pointer object.

> In theory, I should be able to use a custom pointer type and deleter in order to have `unique_ptr` manage an object that is not a pointer.

No, you should not. That is, in terms of getting it to compile and run, maybe, but you simply shouldn't use a `unique_ptr` to manage something which is not a pointer: It will confuse readers of your code, and is error-prone through confusing and due the need to remember the special semantics of this non-pointer-pointer. You absolutely should write an appropriate RAII class for your resource - e.g. an OS file descriptor - or use an existing such class from some library. Only if you want a *pointer* to such a resource does a unique_ptr make sense; but then, you don't need a custom deleter.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on Nicol Bolas answer:

```
struct FdDeleter
{
    typedef int pointer;
    void operator()(int fd)
    {
        ::close(fd);
    }
};
typedef std::unique_ptr<int, FdDeleter> UniqueFd;
```

It's short, but you have to avoid to compare UniqueFd instance with nullptr and use it as boolean expression:

```cpp
UniqueFd fd(-1, FdDeleter()); //correct
//UniqueFd fd(nullptr, FdDeleter()); //compiler error
if (fd.get() != -1) //correct
{
    std::cout << "Ok: it is not printed" << std::endl;
}
if (fd) //incorrect, avoid
{
    std::cout << "Problem: it is printed" << std::endl;
}
if (fd != nullptr) //incorrect, avoid
{
    std::cout << "Problem: it is printed" << std::endl;
}
return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Making Nicol Bolas class more general:

```
template<class T=void*,T null_val=nullptr>
class Handle
    {
    public:
        Handle(T handle):m_handle(handle){}

        Handle(std::nullptr_t):m_handle(null_val){}

        operator T(){return m_handle;}

        bool operator==(const Handle& other) const
            {return other.m_handle==m_handle;}

    private:
        T m_handle;
    };

typedef Handle<int,-1> FileDescriptor;
typedef Handle<GLuint,0> GlResource; // according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322147/what-is-the-range-of-opengl-texture-id
// ...
```

I am not sure if I should have default template parameter values or not.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using `shared_ptr` rather than `unique_ptr` to manage the life time of `int` handles because the shared ownership semantics are usually a better fit, and because the type of the deleter is erased. You need the following helper:

```
namespace handle_detail
{
    template <class H, class D>
    struct deleter
    {
        deleter( H h, D d ): h_(h), d_(d) { }
        void operator()( H * h ) { (void) d_(h_); }
        H h_;
        D d_;
    };
}

template <class H,class D>
std::shared_ptr<H const>
make_handle( H h, D d )
{
    std::shared_ptr<H> p((H *)0,handle_detail::deleter<H,D>(h,d));
    return std::shared_ptr<H const>(
        p,
        &std::get_deleter<handle_detail::deleter<H,D> >(p)->h_ );
}
```

To use with a file descriptor:

```
int fh = open("readme.txt", O_RDONLY); // Check for errors though.
std::shared_ptr<int const> f = make_handle(fh, &close);
```

Comment: Seems overly cumbersome, a better way would be to let `std::shared_ptr` simply allocate and `int` and then `close()` it in a custom deleter. Then you would also be able to access the descriptor by `*ptr` or `ptr.get()` as usual.

Comment: The `make_handle` approach also lets you access the descriptor by `*ptr` or `ptr.get()`. The handle, e.g. the `int` value, is stored in the custom deleter object, which is needed no matter what in order to call e.g. `close()`.

Comment: Ah, I see, `std::shared_ptr` _aliasing ctor_... seems esoteric enough :) Thanks, I guess I learned something new today.