# Am I using the pointer class properly in this generic unique_ptr<>() deleter?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, ubuntu-16.04, unique-ptr

I created a generic deleter template that can be used to create `unique_ptr<>()` sub-types allowing for a `Deleter` other than just `delete ptr`.

It works great with the default optimization flags (i.e. `-O0`), however, when I use `-O3` the `T & operator * ()` function, somehow, returns `0` instead of the `f_pointer` contents.

I would like to make sure that we agree that there is something wrong in the compiler and that my template is correct. The following is a complete piece of code that should compile as is under Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 and probably other versions as long as they support C++14 (see below for tested g++ versions).

```
// RAII Generic Deleter -- allow for any type of RAII deleter
//
// To break compile with:
//     g++ --std=c++14 -O3 -DNDEBUG ~/tmp/b.cpp -o b

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

template<class T, T null_value, class D, D deleter>
class raii_generic_deleter
{
public:
    class pointer
    {
    private:
        T f_pointer = null_value;

    public:
        pointer(T p)
            : f_pointer(p)
        {
        }

        pointer(std::nullptr_t = nullptr)
            : f_pointer(null_value)
        {
        }

        explicit operator bool () const
        {
            return f_pointer != null_value;
        }

        bool operator == (pointer const rhs) const
        {
            return f_pointer == rhs.f_pointer;
        }

        bool operator != (pointer const rhs) const
        {
            return f_pointer != rhs.f_pointer;
        }

        T & operator * ()
        {
            return f_pointer;
        }
    };

    void operator () (pointer p)
    {
        deleter(*p);
    }
};


typedef std::unique_ptr<int,
            raii_generic_deleter<int, -1, decltype(&::close), &::close>>
                        raii_fd_t;


int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    int fd = -1;

    {
        raii_fd_t safe_fd;

        std::cout << "default initialization: safe_fd = " << *safe_fd
                  << std::endl;

        fd = open("/tmp/abc.tmp", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0700);

        std::cout << "fd = " << fd << std::endl;

        safe_fd.reset(fd);

        std::cout << "safe_fd after the reset(" << fd
                  << ") = " << *safe_fd << std::endl;
    }

    if(fd != -1)
    {
        // assuming the safe_fd worked as expected, this call returns an error
        //
        int r = close(fd);
        int e(errno);

        std::cout << "second close returned " << r
                  << " (errno = " << e << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(For original, see [raii_generic_deleter.h](https://github.com/m2osw/snapwebsites/blob/master/libsnapwebsites/src/snapwebsites/raii_generic_deleter.h) in libsnapwebsites)

There is the output I'm getting when I use `-O0` (no optimizations):

```
default initialization: safe_fd = -1
fd = 3
safe_fd after the reset(3) = 3
second close returned -1 (errno = 9)
```

In this case the `*safe_fd` call returns `-1` and `3` as expected. This calls the template `T & pointer::operator * ()` function.

With any level of optimization (`-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`) the output looks like this:

```
default initialization: safe_fd = 0
fd = 3
safe_fd after the reset(3) = 0
second close returned -1 (errno = 9)
```

As we can see, the safe file descriptor returns `0` instead of `-1` after initialization and then again `0` when it should then be `3`. However, the destructor properly closes the file since the second close fails as expected. In other words, somehow, the file description (`3`) is known and properly used by the deleter.

When I update the pointer operator in this way:

```
        T & operator * ()
        {
            std::cout << "f_pointer within operator * = " << f_pointer
                      << std::endl;
            return f_pointer;
        }
```

Then the output with any level of optimization is correct:

```
f_pointer within operator * = -1
default initialization: safe_fd = -1
fd = 3
f_pointer within operator * = 3
safe_fd after the reset(3) = 3
f_pointer within operator * = 3
second close returned -1 (errno = 9)
```

Which is probably because that specific function doesn't get optimized out completely.

Compilers:

I tested with stock g++ on Ubuntu 16.04

> g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

And also on Ubuntu 18.04

> g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0

I also went ahead and reported this as a [bug on the GNU website](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86296).

Comment: This doesn't compile with libc++.

Comment: @n.m. It doesn't compiler or link? On what OS did you try?

Comment: Doesn't compile because of const correctness. Tried on Linux and cygwin. Can be fixed by making `f_pointer` mutable and `operator*` a const member function returning non-const ref (reasonable if you think about it a bit). It doesn't affect the main problem though.

Comment: My code is based on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756960/using-unique-ptr-to-control-a-file-descriptor#48575395 which has a non-const `T & operator * ()` function and I have not really found a good document about properly implementing the `pointer` class.

Comment: As I said const correctness is a different issue altogether. After a fix with libc++ the output is as expected and with libstdc++ it's not. With libstdc++, the `default ctor of `safe_fd` doesn't seem to initialize `f_pointer` to -1. It looks like value initialisation for `pointer` inside `unique_ptr` isn't performed.

Comment: Correction, value init seems to be performed ok, but opeeator\* looks broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using unique\_ptr to control a file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756960/using-unique-ptr-to-control-a-file-descriptor)

Comment: @BrunoMartinez Although you have the right answer now, you had the bug I ask about here and you did NOT have the right answer before. Not only that, the accepted answer has a very ugly version which is ultra specialized. Not a nice template like you and I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be due to libstdc++ implementation of `unique_ptr::operator*`. Here it is in a very simplified, pared-down way:

```
struct pointer
{
    pointer(int val = -42) : z(val) { }
    int z = -42;
    int& operator*() { return z; }
};

struct my_unique_ptr
{
    pointer rep;
    pointer get() { return rep; }
#ifdef PROBLEM
    int& operator*() { return *get(); } // libstdc++ implementation
#else
    int& operator*() { return *rep; } // libc++ implementation
#endif
};

int main()
{
    my_unique_ptr q;
    std::cout << *q << "\n";
}
```

Now it is abundantly clear that libstdc++ cannot possibly work with your implementation of `pointer`, because it returns a reference to a local temporary object from `operator*`. Any `pointer` that stores its own pointee will have the same issue.

Standard-wise, this doesn't seem to be a bug in libstdc++. The standard specifies that `unique_ptr::operator*()` returns `*get()`, which libstdc++ faithfully does.

If anything, this is a defect in the standard.

An immediate fix is to stop defining `operator*` in your `pointer` class. `unique_ptr` doesn't need it (NullablePointer is not required to provide it).

Since `pointer` is in fact nothing more than a wrapper around `T` that provides value-initialisation to a given constant, it would make more sense to define an `operator T()` for it, and use `get()` to "dereference" the corresponding `unique_ptr`.

Comment: NullablPointer doesn't define an `operator * ()`, but without it I can't compile. _(/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:291:9: error: no match for ‘operator*’)_ Having an `operator T ()` or a `get()` doesn't help either. I just think that it's not possible to use `unique_ptr<>()` that way at the moment...

Comment: It only doesn't compile because you use `operator*`. If you remove all `*save_fd` and also `*p` it compiles jolly well (checked with 3 versions of gcc and 2 of clang). Replace with `int(save_fd,get())` and `T(p)` respectively.

Comment: `int& operator*() { return A_MEMBER; }` Without checking whether it's technically correct, that looks like gross abuse of the notion of a "pointer". *Even if some standard text says it's correct doesn't mean that it was ever intended to be*. Or that it will still be "supported" (in theory) in future revisions. (I also hate the semantics of input operators, but at least everybody knows they are very degenerate forms of forward iterators, and the use pattern is stereotypical.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my own answer to show the changes in the code for others interested by such an RAII deleter (very practical as you don't need to specify the deleter each time you have an instantiation!).

As mentioned by @n.m. in the accepted answer, `int` is not a pointer and thus as such it can't be accessed as a pointer. So the `T & operator * ()` is not logical for such a type (as `operator [] ()` and `operator -> ()` would also not make sense).

The problem with the code is because of the `get()` being used by the `operator * ()` in the `unique_ptr<>()` implementation. It looks like this:

```
/// Return the stored pointer.
pointer
get() const noexcept
{ return std::get<0>(_M_t); }
```

As we can see, the `get()` returns a `pointer` copy. Such an object is temporary! This means you can't return a reference from it and hope for it to remain valid. The `operator * ()` does such, though:

```
/// Dereference the stored pointer.
typename add_lvalue_reference<element_type>::type
operator*() const
{
  _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_ASSERT(get() != pointer());
  return *get();
}
```

As we can see, this function returns the content of the reference returned by `get()` but then says it wants a reference. This is why my `operator * ()` implementation had to return a non-const reference.

By removing that constrain and using `operator T () const` instead of `operator * ()` to retrieve the value of the `unique_ptr<>()`, I get the correct value.

```
// RAII Generic Deleter -- allow for any type of RAII deleter
//
// To break compile with:
//     g++ --std=c++14 -O3 -DNDEBUG ~/tmp/b.cpp -o b

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

template<class T, T null_value, class D, D deleter>
class raii_generic_deleter
{
public:
    class pointer
    {
    private:
        T f_pointer = null_value;

    public:
        pointer(T p)
            : f_pointer(p)
        {
        }

        pointer(std::nullptr_t = nullptr)
            : f_pointer(null_value)
        {
        }

        explicit operator bool () const
        {
            return f_pointer != null_value;
        }

        bool operator == (pointer const rhs) const
        {
            return f_pointer == rhs.f_pointer;
        }

        bool operator != (pointer const rhs) const
        {
            return f_pointer != rhs.f_pointer;
        }

        operator T () const
        {
            return f_pointer;
        }
    };

    void operator () (pointer p)
    {
        deleter(static_cast<T>(p));
    }
};


typedef std::unique_ptr<int,
            raii_generic_deleter<int, -1, decltype(&::close), &::close>>
                        raii_fd_t;


int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    int fd = -1;

    {
        raii_fd_t safe_fd;

        std::cout << "default initialization: safe_fd = " << safe_fd.get()
                  << std::endl;

        fd = open("/tmp/abc.tmp", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0700);

        std::cout << "fd = " << fd << std::endl;

        safe_fd.reset(fd);

        std::cout << "safe_fd after the reset(" << fd
                  << ") = " << safe_fd.get() << std::endl;
    }

    if(fd != -1)
    {
        // assuming the safe_fd worked as expected, this call returns an error
        //
        int r = close(fd);
        int e(errno);

        std::cout << "second close returned " << r
                  << " (errno = " << e << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So two main changes (1) `T & operator * ()` has become `operator T () const` and (2) in `main()`, change `*safe_fd` in `safe_fd.get()`.

Note: I also cast `f_pointer` to `T` for the deleter function in case the deleter function is not a one to one match and automatic casting would fail. (i.e. in my case here `close(int)` has an exact `T` as input so it would work just fine. At times the deleter may not be that perfect.)